# How do this become a Iref current source?

Tags: current-source

It is a Iref current source unit

[image]

It is PFET. It is used in one of the data converters block. What is it and how does it work?

Comment: draw you circuit with the tool

Comment: What is your background? Do you know about regular PMOS current sources? Also, I believe that the bulk (you called it NWELL) should typically be tied to VDD.

Comment: i am a beginner and i know about current source. but this is just stacked pfets. bulk is connected to VDD assume that only. @sven

Thanks transistor.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit consists of 3 transistors in series. I will name them from top to bottom: M1, M2 and M3.

These three transistors combined will work like a modified single PMOS transistor. M1 and M2 will both operate in the triode region, as their \$v_{DS}\$ is kept small by the \$v_{GS}\$ of M3. So this is in essence a source-degenerated PMOS current source. The equivalent resistances of M1 and M2 will scale approximately with \$v_{GS}-v_{TH}\$.

If the voltage at the drain of M3 is low enough, then M3 will be in saturation and you will get a high output impedance. Hence it can be biased as a current source.

Comment: Hi Sven B, how their(M! and M2's) VDS is kept small by the VGS of M3? How their equivalent R is approx. VGS-VTH?

Comment: Because they all need a vgs > vth to work, so the source needs to be at least vth lower than the gate. The simplest mosfet model equations will also give you that a transistor in the triode region is approximated by a resistor **proportional** to vgs-vth. Not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If the 3 transistors were of equal size (which they would usually be to provide predictable performance), then they are equivalent to a single device with 3 the length of an individual one. If of different sizes, then they might be *approximately* the same as a device with the same total number of combined 'squares' (Length/Width), but likely output impedance, short channel effects and mask over/under etch  effects would affect that calculation.

Then, a single (effective) device with a fixed VGS can act as a current source if VDS > (VGS-VTH).